# Package manager to get re2c on my Andriod phone

Tags: android, open-source, package-manager

I have an Android phone. I kind of am confused about the package managers; I think I have `Play Store`, `F-Droid`, and `apt-get` from `Termux`. I really miss [re2c](https://re2c.org/); `apt-get install re2c` says `E: Unable to locate package re2c`. Is it possible to install `re2c`, whether with my existing or a new package manager, on my phone?

Comment: Have you simply tried to build `re2c` on your own in a termux environment? BTW: if a package is available or not does not depend on the package manager but on the used repositories. And someone have to provide that package in a repository.

Comment: @Robert Yes, but `autotools` and `cmake` from the build instructions are also not present. I would be open to tips to build it without the support of a package manager.